# Replace string such that it doesn't conflict with child elements

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, replace

Suppose I hve this some markup

`<p> 
hello there <a>say hello</a>
</p>`

And I would like to replace every instance of a string that is not within a `<a>` tag by an `<a>` tag. Example say the word I am trying to replace in this example is `hello` with `<a>hello</a>` if I called a `string.replace("hello","<a>hello</a>")` it would replace **both** `hellos` leaving me with
`<p> 
<a>hello</a> there <a>say <a>hello</a></a>
</p>`

when what I really wanted was
`<p> 
<a>hello</a> there <a>say hello</a>
</p>`

Is there a way to separate the actual text of an element without its children? or better yet. Is it possible to write a regex that ignores matching text surrounded by a set `<a> </a>`?

Comment: DOM manipulation will be efficient in this case.

Comment: Regex 'if there is not "<a>" before str1, replace str1 with str2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain about a way of detecting occurrences of hello not contained in an `<a>` tag, but the following will do what you want it to do.

The basic concept is to split the content into two arrays: one that contains the plain text, and the other that contains the links. The `map` function handles the replacement method on the plain text, then the loop afterward stitches the two arrays back together into an output string.

```js
"use strict";
var test = "hello there <a>say hello</a>"

function addLinksToHello(str) {
  var linkrgx = /<a.*?>.+?<\/a>/gi,
    plaintext = str.split(linkrgx),
    links = str.match(linkrgx)

  console.log(plaintext)
  console.log(links)

  plaintext = plaintext.map(txt => txt.replace('hello', '<a>hello</a>'))

  console.log(plaintext)

  //rebuild string
  var len = -1,
    merged = []
  while (++len < plaintext.length) {
    merged.push(plaintext[len])
    if (links[len]) merged.push(links[len])
  }

  console.log(merged)

  return merged.join("")
}

var addedlink = addLinksToHello(test)

console.log(addedlink)
```

Comment: You are the hero we need.